# Multivariable Chain Rule / Partial Derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

If $z = f(x − y)$ and $g(x, y) = x − y$, so that $z =f∘g$

Why/How does the chain rule imply this?

$$\frac{∂z}{∂x} =\frac{∂f}{∂g}\frac{∂g}{∂x} =\frac{∂f}{∂g}$$

and

$$\frac{∂z}{∂y}=\frac{∂f}{∂g}\frac{∂g}{∂y} =-\frac{∂f}{∂g}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just note that $z = f(x-y)$ is one variable function depend on $g = x-y$. Because $z = f (g(x,y))$,
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f(g(x,y))}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g} \cdot 1 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}
$$
and the same thing for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.

Comment: i guess i am confused as to how come for z = f(x-y), we can write it using partial f instead of partial z

Comment: so can we write   $\frac{∂z}{∂x}$  in terms of z instead of f?

Comment: i guess what im saying is that most of the problems i encountered had a straight forward chain rule with 2 functions while this problem has z = a chain rule which threw me off

Comment: Yes you can. Because  f: R --> R just single variable function f(u)=z

Comment: To avoid confusion it useful to look back to the theorem and trying to apply that to examples.